# Connection between cross entropy and likelihood for multi-class soft label classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, predictive-modeling

The connection between cross entropy and log likelihood is widely expressed for the case when sample multi-class labels are one hot binary vectors (basically the same). Cross entropy is defined when labels are not one-hot but any valid probability distribution.

What is the relation between the general cross entropy and log-likelihood?

**One-hot case**

Both log likelihood and cross entropy come down to:

$-\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_k1\{{y_i^{(k)}=1\}}{\log{\hat{y}_i^{(k)}}}(\theta)$

When:

$i$ - the sample index
$k$ - the class index
$\theta$ - model parameters
$y$ - samples labels (one-hot vector)
$\hat{y}$ - predictions (probability distribution like vector)
$1\{\}$ - indicator function

**General case** ($y_i$ is probability distribution)

Cross entropy can be reduced to:
$-\sum\limits_{i}y_i\log\hat{y}_i(\theta)$

How does this relate to log-likelihood?

Comment: Which log likelihood? Every dfistribution has a log likelihood. You should be concrete and post the equations you're describing here. I suspect that what you're referring to as "cross entropy" *is* the log likelihood of the multinomial distribution, but to be sure you should be concrete about both.

Comment: @DavidMarx Added more details. I hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you are asking how log likelihood in a multi-class classification problem relates to the cross entropy loss. So here is my try:

Assuming we have a multi class classification problem ($C$ different classes) where we estimated the conditional probabilities for each class given the data $\textbf{X} = \{ (\textbf{x}_i , y_i)_{i=1}^N \}$ (e.g., using a neural network) and where the classes are *one-hot encoded*:
$$
\hat{p}_i^{(k)} \in [0, 1] \quad \text{denotes the estimated probability of the } i\text{th sample for the } k\text{th class}\\
p_i^{(k)}\in \{0, 1\}\quad \text{denotes the true probability of the } i\text{th sample for the } k\text{th class}\\
y_i^{(k)} = p_i^{(k)} = 1_{y_{i}^{(k)}==1} \quad \text{hard labels, i.e.,} \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }i \text{th sample belongs to } k\text{th class},\\ 0 &\text{else.}\end{cases}
$$
Note that $\hat{p}_i^{(k)} = \hat{p}_i^{(k)} (\textbf{x}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta})$ is actually a function that depends on parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (e.g., network weights) and the input data $\textbf{x}_i$. In the end, we want to optimize the parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. For the sake of simplicity, we just write $\hat{p}_i^{(k)}$ (silently knowing that these estimated probabilities come from some kind of function approximator).

The idea of *maximum likelihood* (or rather the *maximum likelihood estimator*) is to find the optimal model parameters $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ by maximizing a *likelihood function* which estimates the likelihood our model parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ given the observed data $\textbf{X}$, i.e.,
$$
 \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} P \big(\boldsymbol{\theta} | \textbf{X} \big) \stackrel{Bayes}{=} \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \frac { P(\textbf{X} | \boldsymbol{\theta}) P (\boldsymbol{\theta}) } { P(\textbf{X}) } = 
\arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} P\big( \textbf{X} | \boldsymbol{\theta}\big) P(\boldsymbol{\theta}),
$$
where $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ is commonly referred to as *maximum likelihood estimator*, $P(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ can be used to encode prior knowledge (e.g., making some parameters more probable without any information about the data) and is therefore termed *prior distribution*. If we have no prior knowledge about the model parameters (which is usually the case when using neural networks), we can use a uniform distribution making each parameter vector equally likely, such that the maximum likelihood estimator reduces to
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} P\big( \textbf{X} | \boldsymbol{\theta} \big) \stackrel{i.i.d}{=} \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \prod_{i=1}^N P\Big( (\textbf{x}_i, y_i) | \boldsymbol{\theta}\Big), 
$$
where *i.i.d.* denotes the assumption that our observations are independent and identically distributed.

Lastly, we need to identify how we can express $P\Big( (\textbf{x}_i, y_i) | \boldsymbol{\theta}\Big)$ in terms of the true $\textbf{p}_i$ and estimated $\hat{\textbf{p}}_i$ probability vectors. Do we know something about the true probability distribution? .... Yes! It is a categorical distribution, i.e., each sample $\textbf{x}_i$ has exactly one class assigned (Thus, we have as as stated in the beginning $y_i^{(k)} = p_i^{(k)} = 1_{y_i^{(k)}==1}$). A very neat formulation for the likelihood of categorical distributions is as follows:
$$
P\Big( (\textbf{x}_i, y_i) | \boldsymbol{\theta} \Big) = \prod_{k=1}^C \left(\hat{p}_i^{(k)}\right)^{1_{y_i^{(k)}==1}}
$$

Let's take a moment to digest this formula. It's actually pretty easy what we are doing here, we want that the estimated conditional probabilities $\hat{p}_i^{(k)} \in [0, 1]$ correspond to the true labels $p_i^{(k)}\in \{0, 1\}$. Note that the true labels are *hard labels*, e.g., $\textbf{p}_0 = \begin{bmatrix}0 &1&0 \end{bmatrix}^{\text{T}}$, but the predictions are (probably) *soft labels*, e.g., $\hat{\textbf{p}}_0 = \begin{bmatrix}0.2 &0.7&0.1 \end{bmatrix}^{\text{T}}$. We optimize our likelihood by maximizing the predicted probability of the true label, i.e., where the label $y_i$ corresponds to the class $k$, this is denoted by the indicator function $1_{y_i^{(k)} == 1}$

The maximum likelihood estimator can be rewritten to
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} P(\textbf{X}|\boldsymbol{\theta})= \arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^C \left(\hat{p}_i^{(k)}\right)^{1_{y_i^{(k)}==1}} =
\arg\max_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^C \left(\hat{p}_i^{(k)}\right)^{p_i^{(k)}} 
$$

Now we take the negative log-likelihood (hence the maximization problem becomes a minimization problem):
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \arg\min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \Big(-\log P(\textbf{X}|\boldsymbol{\theta})\Big) = \arg\min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \left(- \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^C p_i^{(k)} \cdot \log \left(\hat{p}_i^{(k)}\right) \right)
$$
(This formula is the same as in your question).

Let's suppose, there is only one datapoint $N=1$, then we get
$$
- \sum_{k=1}^C p^{(k)} \cdot \log \left(\hat{p}^{(k)}\right) = H(p, \hat{p})
$$
This is known as the *cross-entropy loss*, i.e., **minimization of the cross-entropy loss corresponds to maximum likelihood when hard labels are provided**.